# TinyMCE not include https/https when embed video

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

i want to embed video using tinymce media plugin. The embed link has https://player.vimeo.com but when to save it, it converted to //player.vimeo.com.

How to resolve this problem? I want to include http/https

Here is my javascript config

```
extended_valid_elements : "video[autoplay|muted|loop|playsinline|class]",
relative_urls: false,
remove_script_host: false,
```

Answer (score 1):

tinymce uses [Protocol-relative URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#prurl).

At one time, this [was recommended to do](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), which is why this was implemented; however, you should open a ticket for them as going forward, [it should be avoided](https://jeremywagner.me/blog/stop-using-the-protocol-relative-url/).

Seems like this is an outstanding issue: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3889

Comment: Thank you for this! Fixed in TinyMCE 5.2.0 https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4479#issuecomment-620294492